# Multiple scrolls with element fixation in Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

Faced a very non-trivial problem, I can not figure out how to solve it yet.
Here is an example of code parts:

```
Column(
        modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxSize()
        .verticalScroll(scrollState)
        .weight(1f)
       ) {
            Box1 (),
            Box2 (),
            VerticalGrid ()
          }
       )
```

The task is this: when scrolling down, Box1 should be smoothly hidden (since we scrolled it), when scrolling up, it should appear;
Box2 should always be visible (since it is essentially a search field) and when scrolling down, it should take the place of Box1, and at the same time, the LazyVerticalGrid should scroll with its elements.
Please help, thanks in advance!

P.S. in the usual xml markup, the `app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"` flags seemed to play such a role

Comment: It is a direct use case for a sticky header. But, LazyVerticalGrid does not have sticky header support yet. You can use LazyColumn to simulate a LazyVerticalGrid.

Comment: @Abhimanyu How to understand the "sticky header"? It's just that I don't even have an idea about the implementation of this example yet. I tried to implement it even without LazyVerticalGrid - Box1() and Box2() scrolled together with Column (was made instead of LazyVerticalGrid). And LazyVerticalGrid will not work in conjunction with Column.rememberScrollState, because there is a crash

Comment: @Abhimanyu Thanks for the hint, more or less it turned out to implement the logic. But a problem arose: since now LazyColumn is used instead of Column, it is impossible to insert LazyVerticalGrid, because it cannot be shared with LazyColumn

Comment: Yes, lazy columns and lazy grids cannot be used together. You have to simulate a LazyGrid using Rows and Cells in a LazyColumn

Comment: @Abhimanyu I tried to solve the problem by adding the .height() modifier to the LazyVerticatlGrid. Don't know how dirty this hack is. Example: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1ANt65eoNhQ&t=896s